# How to properly set DataStore for storing boolean value

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-datastore

I want to set a simple switch that'll save a boolean value and if then block in my function.

Currently I have this in my DataStore:

```
    companion object {
        private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("userToken")
        private val AutoRestartSystemUI = booleanPreferencesKey("AutoRestartSystemUIValue")


    }

    var getAutoRestartSystemUIValue: Flow<Boolean> = context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        (preferences[AutoRestartSystemUI] ?: "") as Boolean
    }

    suspend fun setAutoRestartSystemUI(value: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[AutoRestartSystemUI] = value
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Button(onClick = {

                           // if [pro.themed.manager.UserStore(context).getAutoRestartSystemUIValue = true] ()

                            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                                UserStore(context).setAutoRestartSystemUI(false)
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(text = UserStore(context).getAutoRestartSystemUIValue.collectAsState(
                                initial = ""
                            ).toString())

                        }
```

in my activity. I have generally no idea of what I should do next and for some weird reason instead of showing value in a text (temp solution for testing) i have

[image: This]

How do i simplify datastore? How do I properly implement switch that'll make it = !it? How to set default value?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to add your prefences key to you PreferencesKeys companion object as **booleanPreferencesKey**

```
private object PreferencesKeys {
    val AUTO_RESTART_SYSTEM_UI = booleanPreferencesKey("auto_restart_system_ui") }
```

Then basicly you can call it without as Boolean because it is stored as a boolean already.

```
val autoRestartSystemUIValue =
    context.dataStore.data.map { preferences: Preferences ->
        preferences[PreferencesKeys.AUTO_RESTART_SYSTEM_UI]
    }
```

Then you can add some null checks when you are calling if needed use that value in Coroutine as well and add first() function to end because it is flow and you need to select first. For example:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    if(UserStore(context).autoRestartSystemUIValue != null && 
        UserStore(context).autoRestartSystemUIValue.first() == false){
       //DO your operation
    }
}
```